# Unable to run Middleman due to warning: circular argument reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleman

On my old machine I can run middleman. I'm now trying to run my site on my new machine (bundle exec middleman), and I'm having issues, running into the warning/error: circular argument reference.

I'm no longer in contact with the person (ex) who set up the app so I'm doing my best to sort through this issue based on my very limited rails knowledge. I've looked up this issue but none of the answers I'm seeing seem to be working.

## Enviroment Info

- macOS high sierra version 10.13
- ruby 2.3.3p222
- middleman v4

Comment: Please add more information to your question like your os, middleman, and ruby version.

Comment: I'm running macOS high sierra version 10.13, ruby 2.3.3p222, and middleman v4.

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile and any errors you run into after running bundle install?